# find the multiple occurrence of a word in a string using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to find the multiple occurrence of a string and also need to find the string after the word which is matched.
I will explain you clearly.

`First  :`

```
$string  = "Apple = A fruit which keeps u healthy\n Ball = Used to play games  \nApple = A fsadasdasdit wasdashich keeps u healthy\n";
$keyword = "apple";
$pattern = '/^.*?\b'.$keyword.'\b.*/i';
$res = preg_match_all($pattern , $string , $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Here, I am trying to find the occurrence of apple in the string. But, it is showing only the first word apple. but it is not showing the second word.

`Second :` If I found all the words which matches the keyword. I need the string after the word.
That means, 
Here, Apple matches two times

first time if the keyword matched, I will get this `Apple = A fruit which keeps u healthy` . 
Now, I need to store `A fruit which keeps u healthy` in one variable.

second time again the apple matched here, I will get `Apple = A fsadasdasdit wasdashich keeps u healthy\n` and I need to store `A fsadasdasdit wasdashich keeps u healthy` in another variable.

Please help me in doing this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this regex:

```
'/\bapple\W*(.*)$/mi'
```

And your desired string is available in matched group #1.

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/nV2mI8

**Code:**

```
$re = '/\b' . $keyword . '\W*(.*)$/mi'; 
$str = 'Apple = A fruit which keeps u healthy
Ball = Used to play games
Apple = A fsadasdasdit wasdashich keeps u healthy'; 
 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: hey, thanks! you solved my first problem. Plz help me in solving the second one too

Comment: Actually if you look closely in the demo link it solved both problems. In the `matched groups` you get your desired text after `Apple = `

Comment: Hey yes.. Sorry, I didnt observed that. Thank u very much anubhav. U r having a great anubhavam. You are helping me second time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$pattern = '/.*?\b'.$keyword.'\b.*(?=[\n\r]|$)/i';
```

I have removed the `^` from the beginning of your regex. And added a lookahead `(?=[\n\r]|$)` at the end to see whether it is followed by a newline or end of string.